# How can I make it so that in MCPE my hunger goes down but mobs don't spawn

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make it where I can play in survival mode and have mobs not spawn, but my hunger still goes down, so not peaceful mode.

Comment: Have you tried playing in peaceful?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

Mobs shouldn't spawn naturally but you will still have the mobs already spawned.